# Writing unit test for jenkins jobs

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins

I have many jenkins jobs which do things like

```
execute myProgram.exe to convert input.txt to output.txt
if (the conversion is successful) {
  trigger another jenkins job
} else {
  send a e-mail to notify someone that the build fails
}
```

All of the them are `Freestyel project`

[image]

I want to write unit test code to test both the success and failure cases of my jenkins jobs.

If the build succeeds, the test code should check if `output.txt`'s content is correct and avoid triggering another jenkins job.

If the build fails, the test code should check if the e-mail was successfully sent to the receiver.

Is there any test framework for doing things like this?

It seems like I can find a solution [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Unit+Test). But I couldn't find examples telling me how to write unit test that uses existing jenkins jobs in that tutorial.

Or should I use another tool (not jenkins) for doing this kind of jobs?

Answer (score 0):

How to test Jenkins Pipelines is currently an ongoing issue; see [JENKINS-33925](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33925).

Though in that thread, you'll see that a couple of people have been working on solutions, e.g. https://github.com/macg33zr/pipelineUnit

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that all of my jenkins jobs are created with `Freestyle project`, not Jenkins Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins Job Builder and describe your jobs in YAML files.

Do your configuration changes in your branch and continuously deploy them to test Jenkins server. 
It is pretty simple with different config files in Jenkins Job Builder.

Run your jobs on test Jenkins master and merge to master after running your jobs.

[Jenkins Job Builder Docs](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/)